# Сделать ссылку в форме на добавление ForeignKey'я

Tags: python, forms, django

Здравствуйте.
Как добавить ссылку к каждому полю, который ForeignKey или ManyToManyField, как в админке:

[image: ссылка на добавление в модель данных]

У меня только идея изменить в самой ModelForm

```
normal_row = u'<tr%(html_class_attr)s><td>%(label)s</td><td>%(errors)s%(field)s<a href="ссылка_к_модели">+</a>%(help_text)s</td></tr>',
```

Вопрос - как можно сделать иначе?

Comment: Например, ссылку "Описание", я так понимаю?

Comment: Нет. Ссылка, которая иконка +, она ссылается на добавление этой модели. Ну если Вы пользовались админкой, то должны понять.
Тут форма отрисовывает поля, если поле ForeignKey | ManyToManyField, то форма создает список всех данных модели, которая указана, в добавок в форму добавляется еще ссылку '+' на добавление данных в модель.

Comment: Я понял, просто привел пример. Нужно сделать это в обычном шаблоне, верно?

Comment: Да, в проекте пытаюсь отказаться от админки джанги, вот пытаюсь сделать удобное добавление данных на самом сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа такого в шаблоне?

```
{{ form.foreign_key }}<a href="http://any.link">+</a>
```

Comment: Ну да. Надо только знать адресс ссылки модели.

Comment: [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) и [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) к вашим услугам

Comment: Не подумал, что это полный ответ. Так тоже можно в принципе, но хотелось бы другой вариант, с использованием виджетов или еще чего нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как сделал.
У админки есть widget [RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L224).
Вот я заменил виджет нужного поля

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets as admin_widgets
from django.contrib.admin.sites import site
from django.forms.widgets import Select

widgets = {
        'group_plan' : admin_widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(Select(), model.group_plan.field.rel, site, can_add_related=True)
    }
```

Параметры:

- Select - передаем виджет, который использует поле
- тут передаем у поля его rel (ссылка на другую модель)
- site - тупо импортируем и передаем
- can`_`add`_`related = True, это значит добавить иконку, если не указывать, то не будет иконки добавления

Конечно еще не полностью, что надо, потому-что ссылка на админку, ну в скором времени как нибудь изменю ее на нужную.